HttpClient with field & dispose or using statement across class methods?
Which example of using HttpClient in a class is preferable?
Set HttpClient as field and use across all methods in class with dispose:
public class HttpClientExampleRepository : IHttpClientExampleRepository, IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public async Task<FooObject> GetFoo()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage? response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("endpoint_url");

        //...
    }

    public async Task<FooObject> GetFooTwo()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage? response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("endpoint_url");

        //...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _httpClient?.Dispose();
    }

}

Set HttpClient individually in each class method with using:
public class HttpClientExampleRepository : IHttpClientExampleRepository, IDisposable
{

    public async Task<FooObject> GetFoo()
    {
        using HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage? response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("endpoint_url");

        //...
    }

    public async Task<FooObject> GetFooTwo()
    {
        using HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage? response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("endpoint_url");

        //...
    }

}

Would your decision change if there was only a single method or not?
Thanks for the feedback!

Neither. Inject it via DI and have the container control its lifetime. Follow the docs of HttpClient (especially the "Remarks" section) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-net-http-httpclient

@Fildor Thanks that makes sense and found some basic examples.
